# how to change name to last name comma first name java

Tags: java, string

I have a question on how to convert a name to last name comma first name. In my case, I am doing this from a static method. I think I did the coding right but when I run it, I get nothing. How can I fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code:

Testing1.java:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Testing1 {

    public static String convertName(String name) {
        String firstName = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" "));
        String lastName = name.substring(name.indexOf(" "));
        String cName =  lastName + firstName;
        return cName;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String name = "Grace Hopper";
        convertName(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: by "Get nothing" do you mean nothing appears on the console?

Comment: well you never output anything...

Comment: Consider reading the "getting started" part on this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: System.out.println( convertName(name) );

Comment: And you aren't adding in the comma between the names either.

Comment: I think he means space instead of comma, based on his code.

Comment: Your code returns `" HopperGrace"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something with the value returned by `convertName()`. For example, print it.

Modify your main method as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String name = "Grace Hopper";
    name = convertName(name);
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

and then you will "get something".

Also you are not adding the comma, just reversing first and last name. And don't forget to sanity-check the input (for example, your code would throw an Exception if the input has no spaces).

Comment: or just `System.out.println(convertName("Grace Hopper"));`

Comment: @dansalmo: Yes indeed. I assume this is a simplified example anyway and that he'll be actually reading data from command line args or from stdin or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't assign the returned value to anything.  I also added the comma, and removed the leading space.

```
public class Testing1 {

    public static String convertName(String name) {
        String firstName = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" "));
        String lastName = name.substring(name.indexOf(" ") + 1); // + 1 to skip the space
        String cName =  lastName + ", " + firstName;  //Add a comma and space
        return cName;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String name = "Grace Hopper";
        name = convertName(name);  //Assign the returned value
        System.out.println(name);  //Print the returned value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change

```
String cName =  lastName + firstName;
```

to

```
String cName =  lastName + ", " + firstName;
```

Otherwise you aren't going to get the comma you wanted in your result.

Comment: It will also still have a leading space.

Answer (score 0):

Read this page: [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), consider using split() to split the name string.  Then reassemble it in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't add the comma.

Secondly, you only called the method, but didn't print the result.

Try this (commented the changes):

```
import java.io.*;

public class Testing1 {

    public static String convertName(String name) {
        String firstName = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" "));
        String lastName = name.substring(name.indexOf(" ") + 1); // add 1
        String cName =  lastName + ", " + firstName; // add a comma
        return cName;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String name = "Grace Hopper";
        System.out.println(convertName(name)); // print the returned name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the comma,store the return value from function in a string and then print the result.

```
public class LastNameFirstName2 {
    public static String convertName(String name) {
        String firstName = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" "));
        String lastName = name.substring(name.indexOf(" "));
        String cName =  lastName + "," + firstName;
        return cName;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String name = "Grace Hopper";
        String ReversedName=convertName(name);
        System.out.println(ReversedName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the recursive algorithm solving the problem which doesn't use any methods of string library. This method does not restrict the number of words in string `str` to 2.

```
public static String convert(String str, int start, int finish) {
    if(start >= finish)
        return "";
    String temp="";
    int i;
    for(i=start;i<finish;i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i) != ' ')
            temp += str.charAt(i);
        else
            break;
    }
    
    return convert(str, i+1, finish) + (convert(str, i+1, finish) == "" ? "" : " ") + temp;
}

public static String nameShuffle(String str) {
    return convert(str, 0, str.length());
}
```